# zxing - generate custom qrcode template

Tags: java, qr-code, zxing

Ok, I thinnk it's more like "where I can find It" than a real question.

I'm using the zxing to build a QR Code engine for my system, it's work really cool, but I need make some customizations.

At https://www.qrcode-monkey.com/ I found a QR Code builder with some templates that can be read for any qr code reader.

The Colors can be changed with MatrixToImageConfig class, but I didn't found a way to change the shape.

Anyone knows a library that do this?!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This class is for change the qr code color.

```
public class QRCodeServiceImpl {
    public static final int ON_COLOR = 0xFFFF9F37;
    public static final int OFF_COLOR = 0xFF6638B6;

    public byte[] buildQRCode(String data) throws WriterException, IOException {
        Hashtable<EncodeHintType, Object> hintMap = new Hashtable<>();
        hintMap.put(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.L);
        hintMap.put(EncodeHintType.MARGIN, 1);
        hintMap.put(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, "UTF-8");

        QRCodeWriter qrCodeWriter = new QRCodeWriter();
        BitMatrix bitMatrix = qrCodeWriter.encode(data, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 512, 512, hintMap);

        ByteArrayOutputStream pngOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        MatrixToImageWriter.writeToStream(bitMatrix, "PNG", pngOutputStream, getMatrixConfig());
        byte[] fileData = pngOutputStream.toByteArray();
        return fileData;
    }

    private MatrixToImageConfig getMatrixConfig() {
        MatrixToImageConfig config = new MatrixToImageConfig(ON_COLOR, OFF_COLOR);
        return config;
    }

}
```